# Loading form before while loop in game

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a game in C# .But it has some infinite loop that prevents form from being loaded. I have tried many solutions available on internet, But that doesn't seems to work.

My problem is :"How to load the form before execution of while loop."?

My Program.cs Source

```
namespace SumSwamp
{
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var window = new Form1();
        window.Show();

    }
}
}
```

Form1.cs :

```
namespace SumSwamp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int DieLargeNum = 0;
    public static int DieSmallNum = 0;
    public static int DieOperator = 0;
    public static int DieTotal = 0;
    public static int TotalSpaces = 42;
    public static int CompSum = 0;
    public static int PlayerSum = 0;
    public static Boolean PlayersRoll = true;
    public static Boolean WaitForRoll = true;
    public static int Turn = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        while(Turn == 0) //INFINITE LOOP
        {
            if (WaitForRoll==false)
            {
                DieTotal=DieLargeNum;
                Random rnd1 = new Random();
                DieLargeNum = rnd1.Next(1, 7);
                if (DieTotal>DieLargeNum)
                {
                    Turn = 1;
                    labelStatus.Text = "Player 1's Turn";
                    WaitForRoll=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Turn = 2;
                    labelStatus.Text = "Player 2's Turn";
                    WaitForRoll = false;
                }
            }
        }

        while ((CompSum < TotalSpaces) & (PlayerSum < TotalSpaces))//INFINITE LOOP
        {
            while (Turn == 1)
            {
                if (WaitForRoll == false)
                {
                    if (DieOperator == 1)
                    {
                        DieTotal = DieLargeNum + DieSmallNum;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (DieLargeNum > DieSmallNum)
                        {
                            DieTotal = DieLargeNum - DieSmallNum;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DieTotal = DieSmallNum - DieLargeNum;
                        }

                    }
                    PlayerSum = PlayerSum + DieTotal;
                    Turn = 2;
                    PlayersRoll = false;
                    labelStatus.Text = "Player 2's Turn";
                }
            }

            while (Turn == 2)
            {
                Random rnd1 = new Random();
                DieLargeNum = rnd1.Next(1, 7);
                Random rnd2 = new Random();
                DieSmallNum = rnd2.Next(1, 7);
                Random rnd3 = new Random();
                DieOperator = rnd3.Next(1, 3);
                labelDieLargeNum.Text = DieLargeNum.ToString();
                labelDieSmallNum.Text = DieSmallNum.ToString();
                if (DieOperator == 1)
                {
                    labelDieOperator.Text = "+";
                }
                else
                {
                    labelDieOperator.Text = "-";

                }

                if (DieOperator == 1)
                {
                    DieTotal = DieLargeNum + DieSmallNum;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (DieLargeNum > DieSmallNum)
                    {
                        DieTotal = DieLargeNum - DieSmallNum;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DieTotal = DieSmallNum - DieLargeNum;
                    }
                }
                CompSum = CompSum + DieTotal; 
                Turn = 1;
                PlayersRoll = true;
                labelStatus.Text = "Player 1's Turn";                    
            }

        }
        if (CompSum>=TotalSpaces)
        {
            labelResult.Text = "CPU Player has won!";
        }
        else
        {
            labelResult.Text = "You win!";
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PlayersRoll == true)
        {
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            DieLargeNum = rnd1.Next(1, 7);
            Random rnd2 = new Random();
            DieSmallNum = rnd2.Next(1, 7);
            Random rnd3 = new Random();
            DieOperator = rnd3.Next(1, 3);
            WaitForRoll = false;
            labelDieLargeNum.Text = DieLargeNum.ToString();
            labelDieSmallNum.Text = DieSmallNum.ToString();
            if(DieOperator == 1)
            {
                labelDieOperator.Text = "+";
            }
            else
            {
                labelDieOperator.Text = "-";

            }

        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Don't use infinite loops, its very bad practice especially in Forms applications. You should look into using timers to call a routine. Looks like you took a console program and stuck it in the form constructor...

Comment: @RonBeyer How to load form before while loop. Thats the question. I cant remove those infinte loops as they are essential

Comment: Move the code out of the constructor and into the load event

Comment: They aren't, because they don't even work (you can't get out of the first one to get to the other ones). You can't move it into the "load" event either because you'll get the same problem. You can't use the same paradigm from a console application into a forms one. This needs a major redesign/rethink to work.

Comment: winforms doesn't work like that. You cannot have an infinite loop anywhere. You need to switch to an event-driven model - that's how winforms works.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your infinite loop in the `Form.Enter()` event, the form will be loaded first and then run your loop. But the UI will be unresponsive if you're really in an infinite loop.

Usually UI games are driven by user interaction with controls. So, instead of an infinite loop where you have "WaitForRoll", you just have a button that says "Roll", and when they click it you run your code for that particular event (of rolling the dice).

If you do have to run a loop while the user isn't interacting with controls, it should be done in a separate thread, like a BackgroundWorker or Task.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend multi-threading as a solution to this particular question. It's just going to get even messier.

Comment: @user3185653 No, I'm afraid that would be out of scope. But basically you could have a button the user could press that would trigger the rolling of his dice. Then you would update something on the form to show what he rolled, what the current totals are, who's turn it is, etc. Then you might have a Timer event that does the same thing for the computer player, and if you did this then you would enable the timer at the end of player 1`s turn. After each turn you would check for a winner and if someone won you might disable the roll button, show the results, and enable a "Play again" button.